# useMemo function is getting executed even though the dependency didnt change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-usememo

I have a parent component which renders everytime data in the react query changes. It is using a child component to which it passes data which should render some cards.

Inside the child component, I used the useMemo() function to make sure if it receives the same data as previously it wouldnt execute the rendering of all the cards.

This is the child component

```
export const VerticalCardsList = (props : VerticalCardsProps) => {

const VerticalCards = useMemo(() => {
    console.log('Executing the useMemo function')
}, [props.verticalCardsData])

return VerticalCards }
```

The parent component calls this in a way like this

```
<VerticalCardsList verticalCardsData={props?.cardsResponse?.data?}  />
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `useMemo` is used to get memoized values. What you want is `memo` and not `useMemo` in this case

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you. I am just trying to stop it from executing all the code again when the data didnt change. Cant I use useMemo for that ?
Can you give a link to what you are talking about ?

Comment: const VerticalCards = useMemo(() will be executed first then it will only execute when dependency change

Comment: Unfortunately thats not happening, it executed everytime, I just sent a static object too, the result is same

Comment: Could you provide how you added a static object to it? And could you also provide the structure of `verticalCardsData`?

Comment: for the sake of testing I sent a plain object everytime const object = { innernumber : 1}

Comment: try exporting `memo(VerticalCardsList )` instead of `useMemo`

Comment: Try memoizing `verticalCardsData` before passing it into the component. Even if you just pass in `{}`, it will technically be a different object every single time due to having a different memory address. The prop IS changing 100%.

Comment: @kanuos Is right. It looks like `VerticalCardsList` is a component, from which you're returning `VerticalCards`, which one can safely assume is a `ReactNode`. If you want to memoize a component, you should use `React.memo()` instead of `useMemo()`. Check out [this helpful video about memoizing in React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-alRbk_zP0&t=1s).